# Why does my source code (written in Eclipse) look different in other text editors?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been using Eclipse to do my CS assignments, as recommended by my professor. However, I've noticed that if I open my source code in a different text editor, my beautiful, perfect formatting looks wrong. I believe the problem lies in tabs. A tab character seems to take up less space in eclipse than in other text editors.

A good chunk of our grade is determined by the neatness of our code. I'm not sure if our programs are graded in eclipse or not, so I'd like to figure out how to make source code have the same formatting regardless of text editor.

Is this a problem with Eclipse? Are there settings I can fiddle with?

Comment: tabs are evil, always use spaces!

Comment: @Jarrod: Spaces are evil, use tabs (for indentation)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably due to your **settings for the tab symbol**. If you really want to indent using tab, make sure it is set to 8 spaces everywhere.

From the [Java coding convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-136091.html#262):

> *Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified. **Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4)**.*

Personally I **always use spaces** to indent my code due to the fact that some people have their tab symbol set to show as 4 spaces.

To set Eclipse to always use spaces, go to

*Window* -> *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Code style* -> *Formatter* -> *Edit*

and set *Tab policy* to *Spaces Only*.

Comment: not necessarily 8 but make sure you replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: Yes, it should be 8 spaces. Updated the answer.

Comment: This confuses me: "Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified. Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4)."  So the unit indentation is 4 spaces. By that logic, wouldn't a tab be 4 spaces as well? Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious

Comment: *By that logic, wouldn't a tab be 4 spaces as well?* -- No, it simply means, that if a line should be indented by, say, 12 spaces, then the indentation of that line must necessarily include some spaces (i.e., it cannot be solely implemented using tab-characters).

Answer (score 0):

The tab size is probably different in other editors. It still is in its raw form a `\t`. Depending on what the editor will display when it encounters one is probably found in the preference. Either way it should be consistent in size all the way across the file.

You could also convert tabs to spaces so it is always the same regardless of editor.

Answer (score 0):

The tab character does not have a defined display width. In notepad, it is displayed as the same width as 8 spaces wide. All code editors should allow the viewer to change the displayed tab width. The convention for code is normally a width equivalent to 4 spaces.

If you're desperate, you could replace all tabs with 4 spaces. However, this is frowned upon by some, and may lose you marks. I'm pretty sure that the advised java coding style advocates the use of tabs, not spaces.

At the end of the day, the marker is a fool if he'll turn down syntax highlighting, and the code editor that comes with it.

Comment: The convention for code is normally a width equivalent to *8 spaces*.

Comment: I've already turned in my assignment, so I'm not desperately trying to fix anything. I've noticed this phenomenon before, and recently my TA made a comment that he's been generous with messed up formatting. In the future, points will be docked possibly. I'd hate to lose points for something as silly as formatting. Is it realistic to have my code look the same accross text editors? How should I approach this?

Comment: @user977195 - by using spaces (as mentioned in all the answers above)